# DialogFlow not detecting date-period for 'today' and 'yesterday'

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have training phrases like:

- How much did my solar panels produce last week
- How much did my solar panels produce last month
- How much did my solar panels produce yesterday
- How much did my solar panels produce today

The last week, last month, yesterday, today, I've marked as date-period.  For last week and last month I get them back like this:

```
"parameters":{"date-period":{"startDate":"2018-08-06T12:00:00+02:00","endDate":"2018-08-12T12:00:00+02:00"}}
```

However when I use **today**  or **yesterday** I'm getting back empty params?
What am I doing wrong?

BTW I'm using the Dutch version, so all my examples are in Dutch.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the composite entity as I have explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51659597/can-you-force-dialogflow-to-extract-the-date-time-entity-instead-of-separate-dat/51659790#51659790). Play with different combination to come up for a better solution for your agent.